# Get validation errors only on #valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with a field where I am validating content in the field. I am using ActiveRecord validations to check for presence of that content. However, I want to be able to save, update, etc, without checking the validity. I do want to get the validity at one specific time, and retrieve the errors from it.

```
validates :my_content_in_field, presence: true, if: :should_validate
attr_accessor :should_validate
```

I want this to pass

```
valid?
```

and this to fail

```
valid?(should_validate: true)
```

And after the failed validation I want all updates and saves to work per usual. Is this possible? I essentially want to leverage ActiveRecords error messages, but not actually validate otherwise.

At the end of the day on Friday, I may just be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can call `valid?(should_validate: true)`. `valid?` method may be called with one parameter called `context` (see [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F)). You should read [a great post on validation contexts](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/04/mastering-rails-validations-contexts/).

This should work:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :something, on: :should_validate
  ...
end

m = MyModel.new
m.valid?                    # No validation happens
m.valid?(:should_validate)  # Validates something
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way is defining a specific method in your code like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :my_content_in_field, presence: true, if: :should_validate
  attr_accessor :should_validate
  alias :super_valid? :valid? 

  # Define a custom loose validation method that
  # will ignore :my_content_in_field
  # 
  # As for the following method, the `context` param
  # is needed to replicate the default signature
  # of `ActiveRecord::Validations::valid?`
  def loosely_valid?(context = nil)
    @should_validate = false
    super_valid? context
  end

  # Tweak the base valid? method
  def valid?(context = nil)
    @should_validate = true
    super_valid? context
  end
end
```

You will always validate the `:my_content_in_field` parameter using the standard `valid?` method unless when you call `loosely_valid?` that will ignore that parameter forcing the `@should_validate` attribute in your model.

This is achieved using a simple `alias` call at the beginning of the method to override the standard `valid?` method from `ActiveRecord`.

This approach will always validate `:my_content_in_field` when creating/updating the model. If you don't need this you can change the code changing those methods like this:

```
  def strictly_valid?(context = nil)
    @should_validate = true
    super_valid? context
  end

  def valid?(context = nil)
    @should_validate = false
    super_valid? context
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to come up with is creating a custom method:

```
validates :my_content_in_field, presence: true, if: :should_validate
attr_reader :should_validate

def has_valid_data?
  @should_validate = true

  stored_valid = valid?

  @should_validate = false

  stored_valid
end
```

So now I get the desired behavior:

```
valid? #=> true
has_valid_data? #=> false
```

And I can collect my ActiveRecord error messages and be on my way. But I'd love to see a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to leverage ActiveRecord error messages and you never need `valid?` to consider this field, a better approach would be to use the errors API directly:

```
def valid_data?
  valid = valid?
  errors.add(:my_field, 'invalid content') unless custom_field_is_valid? # your logic here
  valid && errors.empty?
end
```

This will run the validation on all your other fields, adding their error messages, and then also add an error message for just this field.

Comment: Thanks. That was my original approach, but for about 15 values it was starting to make more sense to try to leverage ActiveRecord's auto errors.